# Exception in Application start method in JavaFx application in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, runtime-error, scenebuilder

I am trying to figure out why I keep getting "Exception in Application start method" errors whenever I try to do Java projects in Eclipse. Every project I create this keeps happening. So I decided to import a project and copy and caste the code to see if it was my code or something else. The imported Java project works fine, however the copied version I built still has the same error as the others. This is the error message from stack trace.

This is the code of the project from the reported error: line 22 is "iChat layout", 31, is
" chat layout"

```
 initChatLayout();
    
    
         private void initChatLayout() {
            try {
                // Load root layout from fxml file.
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                loader.setLocation(ChatClient.class.getResource("view/ClientGUI.fxml"));
                loader.setController(new ClientController());
                chatLayout = (VBox) loader.load();


Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2434)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
    at erub.rb.ru.chat.ChatServer.initServerLayout(ChatServer.java:35)
    at erub.rb.ru.chat.ChatServer.start(ChatServer.java:25)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:185)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application erub.rb.ru.chat.ChatServer
```

Comment: [This seemed to help some people with the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26451990/javafx-exception-in-application-start-method)

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace, as text formatted as code, in the question itself. You can [edit] your question to add this information. Also, please only tag the question with relevant tags; based on your description, you are getting a run-time error, not [tag:compiler-errors].

Comment: Post the complete stack trace, formatted as code, in your question.